# Manual segue with SWRevealViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

There is a great blog post over at http://www.appcoda.com/tag/swrevealviewcontroller/ that goes in to setting up SWRevealViewController which is a great component for slide out side menus (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

Unfortunately, there are no swift examples of how to perform a manual segue.

> Took a cleaner approach to storyboard support. SWRevealViewControllerSegue is now deprecated and you should use SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController and SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController instead.

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! SWRevealViewController;

let viewController = navigationController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ImportFileSelect") as! ImportFileSelect

navigationController.showViewController(viewController, sender: self)
```

This doesn't work though. Any ideas? I've trawled the web for swift examples, my next step is to learn objective c!

Comment: What error are you getting and where?

Answer (score 12):

In order to work you'll need to following steps:

- You need to instantiate the SWRevealViewController and then attach it
  to the root controller.
- Then instantiate the destination controller.
- Then create a navigation controller and set the destination
  controller as the rootViewController
- Finally push the navigation controller with SWReveal

  ```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

  let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController

  self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw

  let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardID") as! NameOfViewController


  let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController)



  sw.pushFrontViewController(navigationController, animated: true)
  ```

Comment: This one is working for me but before make sure the story board connection  is disconnected.

Comment: This works but how do I make it reflect in the rearview which option was selected? Ex. it was the third option in the menu list?

Answer (score 5):

I've kind of made some progress. I can load in a new view controller, but it doesn't animate in anyway. The code to do this, on a button click is:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TARGET_VIEW_CONTROLLER") as! UIViewController
var rvc:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController() as SWRevealViewController
rvc.pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download SWRevealViewController project's zip form [Github](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController).
2. Drag SWRevealViewController.m and SWRevealViewController.h files from zip (SWRevealViewController folder) to your project, and Click “Yes” to the prompted message "Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?"
3. Take a look at storyboard in **RevealControllerStoryboardExample2** project. Design your storyboard with this example.

Comment: Thanks, but I was specifically asking about swift. I can see that code here https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/blob/master/RevealControllerExample2/RevealControllerProject2/RearViewController.m might do it, but I can't translate this to swift.

Comment: Storyboards do not depend on Swift or Obj-C. My answer is specified for Swift, take a look on second step.

Comment: And your link is wrong, this file will be useful for you https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/blob/master/RevealControllerStoryboardExample2/RevealControllerStoryboardExample2/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard Download all project and take a look.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I didn't make myself clear. I have the project working in a swift project absolutely fine. Steps 1 and 2 have been done and are working. What I can't find is a swift code example to manually perform a segue. I have it working with static table cell content without any issue.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you want to configure your SWRevealViewController with segues and storyboard.

Comment: No, thanks, but that's all working well and was pretty easy. It's just how to do a programatic segue in swift. One of those links has helped a bit though, I might be able to translate in to swift, but my objective c is weak.

Comment: I can help if you specify what exactly you want to do. SWRevealViewController has no `showViewController` method. I configure it programmatically with `SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: frontViewController:)`. You can push another front controller with `pushFrontViewController:animated:`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play around with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it should be done, but at least i found a way to do it.

In the TableViewController where u have the slideOut menu do something like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if(indexPath.row == <some position> ){
            let vc: AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YOUR_DESTINATION_IDENTIFIER")
            self.showViewController(vc as! SWRevealViewController, sender: vc)
        }
```

The one that satisfy the condition will segue with default animation, not like the slide out menu normally does.

After, in storyboard, do a normal Reveal View Controller Push controller, and as long as it doesn't satisfy the condition it will exit the slide out menu normally